# How can I connect a MongoDB database to a Teams App

Tags: microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

I am far for being an expert in web development or any app development in general but i have the basics. I want to develop a simple microsoft Teams app for my organisation in order to do HR management. I want to use MongoDB to store the data. However I've spent quite a lot of time on trying to figure out how does the toolkit works. How can I create an teams application in teams using a mongoDB database. Which language should I use, React JS?
If you have any useful links i'll take them.
Thanks for your time guys :)

Comment: at the end, a teams app is not more than a website embedded inside teams. So you would connect to MongoDB like you would when developing a "normal" website

Comment: ok that's pretty useful thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with MongoBD while developing teams apps for my clients. You access the DB through the app you are embedding inside Microsoft Teams.
You can find in [this link](https://github.com/selego/teams-app-nodejs-boilerplate) my simple template for creating a Teams Application with ReactJS, ExpressJS and MongoDB. You would configure your mongoDB on this file: https://github.com/selego/teams-app-nodejs-boilerplate/blob/main/api/src/services/mongo.js.